# Exploring a website's Source code on Python and Text to Speech

Tags: python, web, text-to-speech, speech-recognition-api

I'm new to python and this forum. I am currently using PyCharm, and using it to make a simple code that prints the source code of website on the screen. I saw a video and the code was something like:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup4

url = "Google.com"
S = requests.get(url)
C = s.text
T = BeautifulSoup(C)

print(T)
```

Now I want to read a line in the source code from a website, like a fixed definite line, how am I supposed to do it?

Also, how to use `pyttsx` on Windows in PyCharm. I need a text to speech engine for python.

Is there any way I can use a speech recognition engine on python. I mean online like Google or offline too?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Harsh8V the speech-recognition-api tag is for iOS 10. Just an FYI for future use of that tag.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work . It was I guess , a bug ... 
I did this at the end

```
import requests
len=20 #length of string u want to copy
Url="some random url"
T1=requests.get(Url)
T2=T1.content
Pos=T2.find("Search string")
String=T2[pos:pos+len]
print(String)
```

In my original project the string length was not definite , but I got it to work , by using while loop to copy the string until an ending remarks like `<p>` appear. That worked out too .

I used VBScript for the Speech Synthesis 
And used Google speech recognition .